# mdadm: Disk configuration by UUID

Tags: linux, mdadm

I want to create a soft RAID-5 and use UUIDs im the mdadm config file. So I have four disks with 1 partition each that spans the whole disk. But since the partitons don'5 have a filesystem, blkid does not give a UUID. Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You first create the RAID5 device and then use the UUID of it in your mdadm.conf, not the UUID for a filesystem:

```
# mdadm --detail /dev/md0
/dev/md0:
        Version : 1.2
 ....
           Name : enterprise:0  (local to host enterprise)
           UUID : 7d2bf7e5:dc6edd5c:3ca12e46:8c9e5d4b
         Events : 48

    Number   Major   Minor   RaidDevice State
```

So I have a `mdadm.conf` of

```
ARRAY /dev/md/0 metadata=1.2 UUID=7d2bf7e5:dc6edd5c:3ca12e46:8c9e5d4b name=enterprise:0
```

Comment: From `man mdadm.conf` there's also a DEVICE section which identifies block devices members of the array. So DEVICE seems deprecated?

Comment: I am not aware of it being deprecated.  It just isn't necessary.  The kernel will auto-discover a lot.  AFAIK 99% of the time you don't need to use that.  But I am sure there are situations where it wouldbe useful.

Answer (score 3):

First create your desired raid array with mdadm command.
As soon as this is done you will have a UUID for the md.
Then you can create a mdadm.conf with

```
mdadm --examine --scan > /etc/mdadm.conf
```

Verify later on with `ls -l /dev/disk/by-uuid/`

Comment: On some distributions, the config file is on /dev/mdadm/mdadm.conf. Second, I think you meant >>, which would append to the file (just as a comment for other readers here)

Comment: Just > also works, if you just need that one line in the file. You will overwrite all other settings, of course, but this will have them take on their default values, which was perfect in my case.

Answer (score 1):

Use the entries in `/dev/disk/by-id` to reference the parts of the RAID. For example:

`/dev/disk/by-id/ata-ST9320423AS_5VH56VSB`